# Android cache handling

Tags: android, size

I am caching lots of files in my android app, however am having a problem on nexus 6 marshmallow where its onyl saving one image. then cache cleaning on second one.

```
long MAX_SIZE = 30242880L; 
File cacheDir =  lView.getCacheDir();
long size = Common.getDirSize(cacheDir);
System.out.println(Common.freeMemory(lView.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath())+"entering hereeee"+size);
if (size > Common.freeMemory(lView.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath())) {
    System.out.println("entering hereeee"+size);
    Common.cleanDir(cacheDir, MAX_SIZE);
}
```

11-10 22:57:20.731: I/System.out(19080): -532029440entering hereeee79576

```
static long getDirSize(File dir) {
    long size = 0;
    try {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                size += file.length();
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e1) {

    }

    return size;
}

static long freeMemory(String bath) {
    StatFs statFs = new StatFs(bath);
    long free = (statFs.getFreeBlocks() * statFs.getBlockSize());

    return free;
}
```

Comment: Its entering the if despite 79576 is not greater then 532029440

Comment: It's `-532029440`, not `532029440`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`freeMemory` is returning a negative value because of a int overflow. Change it to

```
static long freeMemory(String bath) {
    StatFs statFs = new StatFs(bath);
    long free = ((long)statFs.getFreeBlocks() * (long)statFs.getBlockSize());

    return free;
}
```